# Why is my break statement not working as it exceeds the condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
add = lambda x,y : x+y
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
count = 0 
for num1 in list1:
    if count > len(list1):
        break
    else:
        print(add(num1,list1[count+1]))
        count += 1
```

In the code above, why is the `for` loop not breaking as it exceeds the condition?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  When I run this code, count reaches 4 as expected, and then the print statement faults because the subscript is out of range.  You have elements 0 through 4, but **count+1** is 5 at that point.

Comment: Why should it break, count won't be bigger than the list length.

Comment: You get a subscript out of range error before you increment count enough to trigger that clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you do not need the `break` statement (nor *lambda expression*). You may write you code as:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    print list1[i] + list1[i+1]
```

Even better to use `zip` here:

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list[1:]):
    print a+b
```

Comment: The lambda doesn't matter. The point is that the `zip` solution is easier to read and you will not get any off-by-one errors or index overflows. It's the more pythonic way to loop over a list and access two items in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop executes once per element in `list1`, so `count` will never be bigger than the length of that list.

Comment: Issue is due to `list1[count+1]`. He is trying to access index + 1. Hence will be failing for last iteration

Comment: But the *question* was about the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've you want to stay with tihs code, change the if statement:

```
if count >= len(list1) - 1:
```

and it will break before running out of the bounds of the list in

```
print(add(num1,list1[count+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
print(add(num1,list1[count+1]))
```

When you use count + 1 you're falling into an index out of range.

To keep your logic, you should use `count + 1 >= len(list1)`

```
for num1 in list1:
    if count + 1 >= len(list1):
        break
    else:
        print(add(num1,list1[count + 1]))
        count += 1
```